# angular2 does select attribute only work on textarea?

Tags: angular

I am very new to angular and I am using the following code to get the selected text inside a textarea

```
<textarea (select)="view(textarea.selectionStart, textarea.selectEnd)" #textarea>Hello World</textarea>
```

Which is working as expected but I was wondering if there are any other tags the (select) attribute could work with.  For example, could it work inside a div or a p tag such that the text within those tags could be selected as well? Or does it only work with textarea because they have the .selectionStart and .selectEnd properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(select)` will **only** work for elements that support the `select` event, as `(select)` is an [**event binding**](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding) on the [`select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/select) event.

Right now, the only elements that natively support the `select` event are `input` and `textarea` elements.

With that said, you can always define [**custom events**](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#custom-events-with-eventemitter) for your components, so if you wanted the concept of a `select` event on a `p` tag, you could create a custom component that wraps the `p`, and use [`EventEmitter`](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) to emit custom events. In your template you would then bind this event by using the `(select)` syntax.